# How to make the compiler to not optimize return value of getter and make it constant

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, optimization, return-value

I have a little problem with a C++ class...
I have a private member `bool clientConnected`.
and a getter `bool isClientConnected() {return clientConnected;}`

now the proble is.. that clientConnected is set from a different thread.

in main I have a loop

```
while (!x.isClientConnected())
{}
```

now if I compile it in Debug config.
All works fine... while exits as soon as clientConnected is set to true.
but if I compile it in Release config.
The compiler optimizes the loop as its constant.
and makes the following:

```
00141C01  cmp         al,bl  
00141C03  je          SDL_main+0A1h (141C01h)
```

the value of al is never updated again.
so its always thinks its false.
I tried also with volatile, same results

how can I prevent this optimization in class so the value will get updated on each call, without having to write something like

```
bool z = x.isClientConnected();
while (!z) { z = x.isClientConnected(); }
```

Comment: you can remove the optimizations from the project settings in VS

Comment: @IonutHulub You can but you never should. If optimizations break your code, your code is wrong. Or your compiler is broken, but that is not the case here, and not the case in 99% of the cases where someone's code is broken by optimizations. And it mostly happens with shitty ancient non-mainstream compilers.

Comment: yep, volatile in front of type fixed the problem

Comment: Simple answer - make your variable `volatile`. But better would be to add some synchronization mechanism - consider semaphore.

Comment: `volatile` does not guarantee that changes are seen by the main thread. that's not what `volatile` is for. read up on it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf According to MSDN `volatile` in MS Wirndows is used for this: "Objects declared as volatile are not used in certain optimizations because their values can change at any time."

Comment: @PiotrNycz First off, that's platform specific. In general `volatile` just means something like "read from/write to the actual memory location every time" (I'm sure a language lawyer will point you to the concrete definition). Second, with CPU caches this is not sufficient to ensure correct (and timely) thread synchronization.

Comment: @delnan I do not want to be volatile advocate, I actually do not use it. But the question is tagged "visual studio" so my understanding is that platform specific answers are expected?

Comment: @PiotrNycz The platform specificness does not necessarily invalidate your point, but it may nevertheless important for some readers. Also, the second point makes that moot.

Comment: I'm kind of confused which answer to choice as the accepted, PiotrNycz's have both methods (thread sync (by semaphore) and volatile) but appeared later than Alf's...

Comment: ok, thanks everybody, I'll pick volatile for now, but will keep thread sync in mind for later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`volatile` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd(v=vs.80).aspx looks like simple answer to your problem:

> "Objects declared as volatile are not used in certain optimizations because their values can change at any time."

```
volatile bool clientConnected;
bool isClientConnected() const volatile {return clientConnected;}
```

---

But - you have loop taking CPU:

```
while (!x.isClientConnected())
{}
```

Better is to wait on semaphore:

```
x.waitForConnected();
void X::waitForConnected()
{
   WaitForSingleObject(m_connectedSemaphore, ,....);
}
```

How to create/use semaphore in MS Windows see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This loop is temporary as I'll remove it and use it in a different non CPU hungry context. But want to know how to avoid this problem with optimization

Comment: then use `volatile bool clientConnected;` if this is temporary solution. And add volatile specifier to your function: `bool isConnected() volatile`.

Answer (score 4):

For a treading issue you need to use threading synchronization, in order to guarantee change propagation from one thread to another.

C++11 has some direct support for threading, but I haven't used that.

If you don't have a compiler that supports that, try Boost threads.

Comment: So I need to sync even if I don't modify the value in other threads?

Comment: @Spider: you don't need to sync for values that are not modified or read by other threads. but your question concerned "clientConnected is set from a different thread". if you also have some non-threading issue, then please post a separate question about that.

Comment: let me make explain better. The Client class, has a static method for socket connection reading and client connection (one client only), so its modifies the class nonstatic member by having the pointer to the instanced class. the main program, calls the "StartThread()" method for client listening, that creates the thread for client waiting, then (in main) its loops to wait till a client is connected, and then do other stuff. The clientConnected member is changed only in Client class, there is no setter only getter. So there should not appear synchronization issues

Comment: So, do I still need to implement thread synchronization for this type of problems?

Comment: @Spider If I may make up a rule of thumb, synchronization issues crop up *any* time *any* memory location *ever changes* and is accessed (read, written, or either exclusively) by more than one thread in its lifetime. This is (intentionally) stricter than most well-defined memory models out there, but that stuff *is* complicated and inhumanly subtle. So yes, you need synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You can trick the compiler by moving the implementation of the method in a source file, and force it to not be inlined (look up the particular syntax for your compiler).

Comment: @Spider sorry, missed that part. Did you try moving the implementation out of the class definition?

Comment: what is interesting... that I tried again with volatile in front of type, and it now worked... as far as I saw it can be after also, but didn't work for me... so anyway, thanks :)

Comment: -1 This is really bad answer for a threading issue. There is no guarantee that changes made in another thread will become visible in the main thread.

Comment: Alf, so is there any other solution? I don't modify the value somewhere else the waitconnection thread, I just read it